# No se ven casi los botones inferiores del emulador de Android en mi aplicación de Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, studio

No se ven casi los botones inferiores del emulador de Android en mi aplicación de Android Studio y no se por qué (siguen estando pero se ven blancos y no se aprecian prácticamente).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el layout?, agrega más información, por favor . revisar [ask], saludos.